# Upload a file to s3 given a https s3 url

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, aws-sdk

I'm trying to copy an object from one an s3 bucket to my s3 bucket, but I'm given a http url of the file like this;

https://not-my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/123456738160996-2019-03-23-eo_branch_cta_view-v2-cf5e81e668466de13406877ad681895f6fdd50f38ab7fdb48193d78210098b81-acZMLZ.csv.gz?Signature=12345678Hr3ght0cOPw7bLz%2FJWM%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=123456&Expires=1554017348

If i throw this is the browser i get a csv no worries at all (note: i've obscured parts of the real url so it won't work for you).

I'm using copyObject API in node with the following parameters:

var params = {
        Bucket: "me-buket", 
        CopySource: "https://not-my-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/123456738160996-2019-03-23-eo_branch_cta_view-v2-cf5e81e668466de13406877ad681895f6fdd50f38ab7fdb48193d78210098b81-acZMLZ.csv.gz?Signature=12345678Hr3ght0cOPw7bLz%2FJWM%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=123456&Expires=1554017348"
        , Key: "data"
    };

I keep getting the error:
"InvalidArgument: Unsupported copy source parameter."

What am I doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

S3 does not support using a pre-signed URL (or any other URL) as `CopySource`.  The value you want is `/${bucket}/${key}` which in this case is `/not-my-bucket/1234567381...acZMLZ.csv.gz` (the leading `https://` replaced by a leading slash, the `.s3.amazonaws.com` removed, and the `?` and everything following it removed).

But... that still isn't likely to work, unless the user invoking `copyObject()` has permission to read the source object directly, which is unlikely... otherwise the third party wouldn't have given you the pre-signed URL.

"Fixing" your request as described above will probably change the error to `AccessDenied`.

Without permission to read the object directly, you can't use `copyObject()`.  You'll need to download the file and then upload it to your bucket in two steps.

Comment: Yep this resolves it, I'm just going to have to etl some other way

Answer (score 0):

The above error indicates that the CopySource paramenter which you are giving is incorrect. The correct way to give CopySource parameter will be as follows:

```
var params = { Bucket: "your_bucket", CopySource: "/source_bucketname_url/sourceobjectkey"};
```

Note : The name of the source bucket and key name of the source object must be separated by a slash (/).

Comment: Thanks for that, but authentication still causes problems